# Excel Active X Command button not working properly

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have an Excel sheet with an ActiveX command button on it. It worked perfectly fine one week ago, but now, all of a sudden, it stopped working on my computer. On other computers it works just fine, so I think I have a wrong setting on my laptop.

I have made tests in new clean excel files and the same behavior occurs.
Now, when I click the button, a new smaller button is created and only if that new button intersects (visually) with the old button, and I click on it (on the new button), the macro is ran.

Also, I don't receive anymore the "Enable macros" or "Enable content" message. Maybe it has something to do with this.

The problem is described also in the picture attached.

Excel Active X command button behavior:

[image: Excel Active X command button behavior]

Note: I have already did the following things, but none fixed the issue:

1. reinstalled Office
2. cleaned-up the registry
3. deleted the .exd files from the temp folder, as mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27434382/excel-2007-issue-pre-programmed-buttons-suddenly-not-working

I don't want to replace the buttons with form control buttons because I prefer the Active X, and also these buttons are present on multiple Excel files and I wouldn't like to edit all of them, especially knowing that on other computers this problem does not exist.

*Later edit:*
The code used for the picture example

```
Sub test()
Range("A1").Value = "something weird happens"
End Sub
```

Comment: There are many reasons I can think of.  Posting the code that runs for any of the button events and any called procedures may help eliminate some of the reasons.

Answer (score 1):

If you work with a docking station, try it without being docked in. 
(It sounds weird, but it worked for us here.)